# React Router - Path component is not rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm working on building a simple hacker news app using React and Redux and I'm having trouble with rendering an individual article page component (the ArticleSingle components).

The routing works fine, but the ArticleSingle component does not render on click.

Here's my Root file, which handles all of the routing:

```
// REACT
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// REACT ROUTER
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// REDUX
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createBrowserHistory();

// COMPONENTS
import AppContainer from './components/containers/AppContainer';
import Home from './components/presentational/Home';
import ArticleSingle from './components/presentational/ArticleSingle';

const Root = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={AppContainer} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/topics/:topic_name/articles" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/articles/:article_id" component={ArticleSingle} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Root;
```

Here's the ArticleSingle component, which is the one that I'm having trouble with. I ultimately want to get it to pass the id from the URL to an action passed down from AppContainer, but I was hoping to get the component to render something on the page (the id) before starting the redux work.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ArticleSingle = ({ params, children }) => (
  <div>
    {params.article_id}
    {children}
  </div>
);
export default ArticleSingle;
```

Here's the Home component, it features a filter bar, what why there are two routes for it

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Components
import Spinner from 'react-spinkit';
import ArticleList from './ArticleList';
import TopicsSubNav from './TopicsSubNav';

const Home = ({
  loading,
  articles,
  topics,
  fetchTopicArticles,
  fetchArticles,
  children
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className="title is-3">Northcoders News</h3>
      <div id="TopicsSubNav">
        {loading && <Spinner name="pacman" color="coral" fadeIn="none" />}
        <TopicsSubNav
          topics={topics}
          onTopicClick={fetchTopicArticles}
          onAllClick={fetchArticles}
        />
      </div>
      {loading && <Spinner name="pacman" color="coral" fadeIn="none" />}
      <ArticleList articles={articles} topics={topics} />
      { children }
    </div>
  );
};

Home.propTypes = {
  articles: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  topics: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
  fetchTopicArticles: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchArticles: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Home;
```

Here's the AppContainer, controls the state for all of the app.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Home from '../presentational/Home';
import ArticleSingle from '../presentational/ArticleSingle';

// Redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions/actions';

class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.fetchArticles();
    this.props.fetchTopics();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Home
          articles={this.props.articles}
          topics={this.props.topics}
          loading={this.props.loading}
          fetchTopicArticles={this.props.fetchTopicArticles}
          fetchArticles={this.props.fetchArticles}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchArticles: () => {
      dispatch(actions.fetchArticles());
    },
    fetchTopics: () => {
      dispatch(actions.fetchTopics());
    },
    fetchTopicArticles: topic => {
      dispatch(actions.fetchTopicArticles(topic));
    },
    fetchArticleById: id => {
      dispatch(actions.fetchArticleById(id));
    }
  };
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    articles: state.articles.data,
    article: state.article,
    topics: state.topics.data,
    loading: state.loading
  };
}

AppContainer.propTypes = {
  articles: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  topics: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
  fetchArticles: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchTopics: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchTopicArticles: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchArticleById: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer);
```

Comment: When you visit /article/someid do you get any console errors? If yes, please show them here. Also,when visiting the same url, what do you see in the browser?

Comment: I'm not getting any console errors, the page stays on the Home component instead of rendering the ArticleSingle. The URL updates correctly on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of issues in your code.

1) Lets say you have `<Route path="/articles/:article_id" component={ArticleSingle} />` - To access the `article_id` in  ArticleSingle Componenet you need to use `props.match.params.article_id`

2) This is your route:

```
<Route path="/" component={AppContainer} />
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
<Route path="/topics/:topic_name/articles" component={Home} />
<Route path="/articles/:article_id" component={ArticleSingle} />
```

Basically when you visit /articles/article-id you are matching the first route `<Route path="/" component={AppContainer} />` and you are getting into it. 
To solve this issue you can do one of the following:

A. use  `exact` in your first two routes. That would be `<Route  exact path="/" component={AppContainer} />` and `<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />`

B. Change the order of your routes and but the homepage root at the bottom like the following:

```
<Route path="/topics/:topic_name/articles" component={Home} />
<Route path="/articles/:article_id" component={ArticleSingle} />
<Route path="/" component={AppContainer} />
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

For the above solutions, I am assuming you are using React Router 4. I got the information I provided you from this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved it!  I'll check out the tutorial too!

Comment: That tutorial is quite comprehensive. You should find all you need on react router 4 :)